# Can't Implement Javascript Animation Logic

Tags: javascript, animation, dom

I want to implement some logic in my Javascript animation, but wherever I try to implement it, it never works. I am trying to make my `navigationOpen` true when the animation is done. But what happens is when I set it in the `renderSlideOutAnimation()` the if statement runs before the `renderSlideOutAnimation` function.

```
function openSlideNavigation() {

    var navigationSlideOut = document.getElementById("navigation-slide"); 
    var naviationTrigger = document.getElementById('menu-dots');
    var navigationOpen = true;

    function renderSlideOutAnimation() {

        var widthValue = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(frame, 17.5);

        function frame() {
            if (widthValue == 100) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            } else {
                widthValue++
                navigationSlideOut.style.width = widthValue + "vw"
            }
        }
    }

    if (navigationOpen == true){
        renderSlideOutAnimation();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look now, I edited it.